# I want to go to the default page ("/") after login (django view problem)

Tags: django

I want to go to the default page ("/") after login

The current login process is as follows.

Thanks if you let me know what I need to modify to change the redirect url to "/"

In other words, I want to request "/" after pressing the login button.
If you know the solution, please let me know.

url pattern

```
     path('login/', views.login, name='login'),
```

views.py

```
login = LoginView.as_view(template_name="accounts/login_form.html")
```

templates

```
{% extends "accounts/layout.html" %}

{% block content %}

    <!-- .container>.row>.col-sm-6.offset-sm-3 -->
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6 offset-sm-3">
                {% include "_form.html" with submit_label="login" %}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endblock content %}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Method 1 - set it in `settings.py`

You can set `settings.LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL` to do this. It should either be a URL or a named url pattern.

#### Method 2 - Use the next `GET` field

In the link to your login view add a ?next query paramter e.g.

`mysite.view/login?next=my_view`

Comment: thanks it's perfect answer problem is sloved LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL is work